# Why can't I have a variable in switch-case statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Here is my code:

```
bool Character::keyPress(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case up_key:
            move(0, -1);
            break;

        case down_key:
            move(0, 1);
            break;

        case left_key:
            move(-1, 0);
            break;

        case right_key:
            move(1,0);
            break;

        default:
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the compiler complains:

```
error C2051: case expression not constant
error C2051: case expression not constant
error C2051: case expression not constant
error C2051: case expression not constant
```

In my header file I have:

```
protected:
    char up_key;
    char down_key;
    char right_key;
    char left_key;
```

I am using [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions) 2008.

Comment: switch case expressions must be compile time constants.  change those to `static const char up_key = 1;` and such, and problem solved.

Comment: Because the Standard says so. It's a remnant of the old days, where `switch` were introduced as a "nicer" presentation that was transformed into an array look-up automagically (and thus required constants). Nowadays it makes less sense, but the syntax has not been changed so...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the error message states, the case expressions must be constant. The compiler builds this as a very fast look-up table at compile time and it can't do that if there is a possibility that the values could change as the program runs.

If you do need them to be variable, not constant, your best bet is to use if/else statements instead.

Comment: is it possible to somehow "see" the output of compiler in this case, and maybe compare it with if/else?

Answer (score 7):

Replace this long clumsy code,

```
switch(c)
{
    case up_key:
        move(0, -1);
        break;

    case down_key:
        move(0, 1);
        break;

    case left_key:
        move(-1, 0);
        break;

    case right_key:
        move(1,0);
        break;

    default:
        return false;
}
```

with something like this:

```
move( (c==right_key) - (c==left_key) , (c==down_key) - (c==up_key) );
```

You can litterly replace that 17 lines long of code with that much more neat single line of code.

Comment: What makes you think that that code is neat?

Comment: It *is* a neat line - maybe you should just add a small explanatory comment to the code to assist the hard-of-reading types ;)

Comment: doesn't it increase time complexity? 4 comparisons, 4 type casts  and 2 arthmatic ops are to be made with ur single line!

Comment: @neckTwi I don't think those extra operations matter, considering that a keypress doesn't happen very often. (Then it is also possible that the compiler might optimize that line to something that is equivalent to the switch–case statement above, although I don't know how much you can trust that it actually does)

Comment: @EralpB It is neat because it consists of less code which _in my opinion_ 1) makes reading the code go faster, and 2) makes writing and maintaining the code less error-prone since you need to make changes to fewer places.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the language doesn't work that way. For example, what would happen if `up_key`, `down_key`, `right_key`, and `left_key` were all equal?

Comment: ,i see what you mean. But if i use if/else and they are all equal??

Comment: Actually, you can have the same value here more than once, though you'll always end up in the first one in the list. With if/else, too, you'll get to the first one and never to the later ones.

Comment: Even if they were all constants, which is the crucial aspect here, the values in the cases must all be distinct.  But the distinctness is not the problem - it is the lack of constness.

Comment: You can't have the same constant twice? I believe GCC allows it, though now you make me unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `switch` statement can take only constants, you know when reading the code that the things you're comparing against are all constants. On the other hand, you would use `if` statements (or some other structure) to compare against variables:

```
if (c == up_key) {
    move(0, -1);
} else if (c == down_key) {
    move(0, 1);
} else ...
```

This provides a distinct difference in structure which can greatly aid those who come after you in reading your code. Imagine if you had to look up every `case` label to see whether it was a variable or not?

Comment: yup, that's what i am gonna do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the compiler generates a jump table, with the values hardcoded in, although I may be wrong. The way the tables are generated just doesn't allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

Since other answers have covered why you are getting an error, here is a way to move in one of the four directions in response to a key press: use lookup tables instead of the conditionals/switches.

Setup portion:

```
std::map<char,pair<int,int> > moves;
moves[up_key] = make_pair(0, -1);
moves[down_key] = make_pair(0, 1);
moves[left_key] = make_pair(-1, 0);
moves[right_key] = make_pair(1, 0);
```

The function:

```
bool Character::keyPress(char c) {
    if (moves.count(c)) {
        pair<int,int> dir = moves[c];
        move(dir.first, dir.second);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//here is the full functional code snippet which can be compiled and run with most of C++  
//compiler/link ...console app was demoed but you can apply the code/logic to win32 app...
//if you have any problem, send me email to Samuel_Ni@yahoo.com

#include <iostream.h>
#include <map>
#include <conio.h>

class CkbdHanler{
  private:
    map<char,pair<int,int> > moves;
  protected:
    char up_key;
    char down_key;
    char right_key;
    char left_key;
  public:

CkbdHanler(char a,char b,char c,char d):up_key(a),
                                        down_key(b),
                                       right_key(c),
                                       left_key(d)
{
    moves[up_key] = make_pair(0, -1);
    moves[down_key] = make_pair(0, 1);
    moves[left_key] = make_pair(-1, 0);
    moves[right_key] = make_pair(1, 0);
 }

bool keyPress(char c){
    if (moves.count(c)) {
            pair<int,int> dir = moves[c];
            move(dir.first, dir.second);
            return true;
   } else return false;

}
void move(int i,int j){
   cout<<"(i,j)=("<<i<<","<<j<<")"<<endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  CkbdHanler CmyKbdH('u','d','l','r');

  cout << "Hello C++... here is a demo of Map to replace switch-case" << endl;
  CmyKbdH.keyPress('d');
  cout << endl << "Press any key to continue...";

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```